# No network traffic when using Fine Uploader with Google Tag Manager on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, fine-uploader, google-tag-manager

We don't have any issues using any other browsers that we've tested (including IE 10+), however when using IE9 we aren't able to upload documents with the fineloader plugin when Google Tag Manager is on the same page.

- No errors are logged into the console
- Using Wireshark, no traffic was detected on the endpoint (C# traditional server, hosted on SharePoint 2013)
- The onSubmit callback is fired
- The onComplete callback is never fired
- The console has the following logged:

  ```
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Parsing template 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Template parsing complete 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Rendering template in DOM. 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Template rendering complete 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Received 1 files or inputs. 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Sending simple upload request for 0 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Sending upload request for 0 
  LOG: [Fine Uploader 5.0.3] Received response for 0_5d0bc1e5-eb23-4458-8a91-d8b74cce01cb
  ```
- Turning on the network trace within IE9, the network traffic is normal up until an attempt is made to upload a document (i.e. the files obtained and their respective HTTP Results are the same as what we get with other browsers
  )
- Once a document is selected to upload, IE9 doesn't post to the endpoint.  However in other browsers, the endpoint is posted to, and a successful (HTTP: 200) response is recorded in the network trace.
- If we remove Google Tag Manager from the page, everything works as expected in all browsers.

To replicate this:

1. If you don't have one, register for a free Google Tag Manager account. http://www.google.com/tagmanager/
2. Create an HTML page with the following markup, and replace lines (7)-(10) with the snippet provided on the Tag Manager site:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
       <title>Test Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
       <noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
       <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) { w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f); })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXX');</script>
       <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/fineuploader.js"></script>

       <div id="fileUploader"> </div>
       <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
           <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
               <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                   <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
               </div>

               <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                   <div>Upload a file</div>
               </div>
               <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                   <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
               </span>
               <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
                   <li>
                       <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                           <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                       </div>
                       <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                       <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                       <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                       <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                       <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                       <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                       <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                       <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                       <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                   </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </script>
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {

               var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                   element: document.getElementById("fileUploader"),
                   request: {
                       endpoint: '/servber/endpoint'
                   },
                   debug: true,
                   autoUpload: true,
               });
           });
       </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Perhaps something on your page is interfering with the library, or perhaps something is intercepting the request.  What do you see in the network tab in IE9?  You'll need to ensure HTTP traffic is captured by the browser or logged in the client by some other entity.

Comment: Hi @RayNicholus,  I've edited the post with the information below.    
- Turning on the network trace within IE9, the network traffic is normal up until an attempt is made to upload a document (i.e. the files obtained and their respective HTTP Results are the same as what we get with other browsers
)
- Once a document is selected to upload, IE9 doesn't post to the endpoint.  However in other browsers, a successful (HTTP: 200) post is recorded in the network trace.

Comment: Are there any security restrictions in place on IE which would prevent it from getting a handle on a file?

Comment: I'm not aware of any security restrictions that should prevent this.  I've tested from a variety of desktops running IE9, including ones that have other browsers installed.

Taking this a step further, I took a desktop with IE11 installed (where this issue does not occur), and emulated IE9 using F12 Developer Tools.  This also failed, exhibiting the same symptoms as mentioned in the original post.

Comment: There are no such known issues with Fine Uploader 5.0.3 in IE9 and older.  So, there is something else here contributing to the issue, perhaps outside of Fine Uploader, perhaps in your web app.  You'll need to provide a link to a site where this can be reproduced so we can investigate further.

Comment: @MarkFeltner are there any specific restrictions that I should be looking out for?

Comment: @RayNicholus Currently we haven't provisioned this on a public facing site, so I'll work on putting an example together.  While the circumstances might be quite different (we are using a traditional server), the last demo (Amazon S3) exhibits very similar behaviour - this being despite having the specific iframeSupport for IE9.  http://fineuploader.com/demos.html

Comment: @user3921130, I don't know exactly, but there are security settings in the `Options` window. Sometimes websites (or zones) can be blocked from certain kinds of traffic.

Comment: I've managed to track down this issue to be caused by having an iframe on the same page.  Google Tag Manager (http://www.google.com/tagmanager/) utilises an iframe on the page to function.  By removing this iframe, fineuploader works in IE9.  Are you able to provide any insight as to how we could get fineuploade not to target this iframe?

Comment: Fine Uploader doesn't target any existing iframes.  It creates its own for each file to be uploaded.

Comment: I've created a sample that can be replicated (and has no dependencies on SharePoint 2013).  Currently, the sample doesn't function, until the Google Tag Manager snippet is removed from the page.  @RayNicholus, any suggestions you can provide that would get these working together would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about google tag manager.  If you provide a link to a running instance of your site where this can be reproduced, I can take a peek.

Comment: Thanks @RayNicholus, are you able to replicate with the sample in the question?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9.

Comment: @RayNicholus are you able to share your network trace from IE9?  In particular, I'd like to confirm that calls to http://googletagmanager.com are successful and calls to your endpoint are (at least) initiated.

Comment: Calls are most definitively initiated to my upload server.  I'll check traffic to tag manager and report back.

Comment: GET request to the tag manager domain on page load, POST to my endpoint on upload.  If you'd like me to investigate further, you'll need to provide a URL of a site where you are able to reproduce this issue.